# Kafka : How to count success/failures with async send

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

**Goal:** Count all success and failures of a Kafka producer on an **async** send.

**Problem :** Sometimes total summation of failure & success doesn't match total entries

**Code example**

```
//class defined below
Counter counter = new Counter();

//we'll say itr has 10 iterations
while(itr.hasNext()){

 counter.incTotal();     

 //busy work
 ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord("myTopic", itr.next());

 //async send
 producer.send(record, new Callback(){
     @Override
     public void synchronized onComplete(RecordMetadata rm, Exception ex) {
        if(ex == null)
          counter.incSuccess();
        else
          counter.incFailure();
     }
 });
}

//this should ensure all async calls have completed
producer.flush();

System.out.println("Total entries " + counter.getTotal() + " : success " + counter.getSuccess() + " failure " + counter.getFailure());
```

**Counter.java**

```
public class Counter {

  private int total = 0;
  private int success = 0;
  private int failure = 0;

  public Counter(){}

  public void incTotal(){
    this.total ++;
  }

  public int getTotal(){
    return total;
  }

  public void incSuccess(){
    this.success ++;
  }

  public int getSuccess(){
    return success;
  }
  public void incFailure(){
    this.failure ++;
  }

  public int getFailure(){
    return failure ;
  }
}
```

Example output : "Total entries 10 : success 3 failure 5"

Comment: Is that a mistake in `getFailure` you are returning `success` ?

Comment: yeah sorry copy paste error -> Its now corrected

Comment: probably try `flush` inside the while loop

Comment: Since the counter can be incremented by different threads you should either make inc methods synchronized or use java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

Comment: Yeah agree with Louri that producer are async call and callback need to synchronize in terms to get correct number so try with AtomicInteger

Comment: @sun_007 thank you for responding. I will give this a shot